# Trigger callback as soon as socket has resolved lookup

Tags: javascript, sockets, http, ssl, dns

I'm trying to run some code which creates tracing spans for the various phases in the lifecycle of an http request (socket, dns lookup, connect or secureConnect, ttfb, end). As of now it looks more or less like this:

```js
function tracedRequest(
    options: HttpRequestOptions | HttpsRequestOptions,
    callback: ResponseCallback
): ClientRequest {
    const isHttps = options.protocol === 'https' || options.agent instanceof HttpsAgent;
    const transport = isHttps ? https.request : http.request;

    const requestSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'request' });

    if (!tracer.isRealSpan(requestSpan)) {
        return transport.call(null, options, callback);
    }

    let socketSpan: ISpan | undefined;
    let dnsSpan: ISpan | undefined;
    let tcpSpan: ISpan | undefined;
    let tlsSpan: ISpan | undefined;
    let ttfbSpan: ISpan | undefined;

    const onLookup = () => {
        dnsSpan?.endSpan();
        tcpSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'http_tcp_handshake' });
    };

    const onConnect = () => {
        tcpSpan?.endSpan();
        if (isHttps) {
            tlsSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'http_tls_handshake' });
        } else {
            ttfbSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'http_ttfb' });
        }
    }

    const onSecureConnect = () => {
        tlsSpan?.endSpan();

        // just in case secureConnect is emmited not only for https transports
        if (isHttps) {
            ttfbSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'http_ttfb' });
        }
    }

    const onResponse = (response: IncomingMessage) => {
        ttfbSpan?.endSpan();

        response.prependOnceListener('end', () => {
            requestSpan.endSpan();
        });
    }

    const onSocket = (socket: Socket | TLSSocket) => {
        socketSpan.endSpan();
        socket.prependOnceListener('lookup', onLookup);

        deferToConnect(socket, {
            connect: onConnect,
            secureConnect: onSecureConnect
        });
    }

    socketSpan = tracer.createChildSpan({ name: 'http_establish_socket' });
    const request: ClientRequest = transport.call(null, options, callback);

    if (request.socket) {
      onSocket(request.socket as any);
    } else {
      request.prependOnceListener('socket', onSocket);
    }

    request.prependOnceListener('response', onResponse);
    return request;
}
```

The problem with this approach arises when you use an agent with keepalive enable. In this situation the socket may be reused, thus the socket already has established a connection to the remote host and neither the socket nor the lookup events will be emitted (notice that for the socket event this is handled, we can know that the socket event will not be emitted if the `request.socket` property is set).

How can I do the same thing for the lookup event ? Which property of the socket object can I check to be sure that the host has already been resolved and the lookup event will not be emitted ? Should I use the `localAddress`/`localPort`, `remoteAddress`/`remotePort` properties or the `socket.address()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some testing and apparently you can do:

```js
if (Object.keys(socket.address()).length) {
    onLookup();
} else {
    socket.prependOnceListener('lookup', onLookup);
}
```

`socket.address()` returns an empty object if an address has not been resolved yet, otherwise it returns an object with the properties `address`, `port` and `family`.

So far it has worked for me